# Finding the power function of the given test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

We have a density $X$ defined as $f(x,\theta)=\theta x^{\theta -1}I_{(0,1)}(x)$.
The hypothesis to test is given as follows:

$H_0:\theta \leq1$ Vs $H_1:\theta >1$

A sample size of two is selected, and the critical region is defined as follows:

$C=\{(x_1,x_2):\frac{3}{4x_1}\leq x_2\}$

I tried writing the power function, which for a general $\theta$ as follows:

$P(\frac{3}{4X_1}\leq X_2)=P(X_1X_2\geq\frac{3}{4} )$

Now since $X_1,X_2$ both are randoms we have to fix one of them, hence:

$P(X_1X_2\geq\frac{3}{4})=P(X_1\geq\frac{3}{4X_2})=\int_0^1 P(X_1\geq\frac{3}{4X_2}|X_2=x_2)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_2$

Am I going in the right direction ?

Evaluating this, gives a $log$ term and hence the value of the integral is coming out to be $\infty$.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you show in more detail how that logarithm arises? I obtain a term proportional to $\log(4/3)$, but that's obviously finite.  BTW, you can simplify the integration by working with variables $Y_i=-\log(X_i)$. The critical region is $0 \lt Y_1+Y_2 \lt \log(4/3)$ and it's easy to compute the distribution of $Y_1+Y_2$, thereby reducing this to a one-variable problem.

Comment: I know its been a while since you asked this question but I really need to know the answer. Do you have it?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{3}{4}\leq x_1\leq 1$ and $\frac{3}{4x_1}\leq x_2$ are integration limits